# Parametrize over a list of values depending on the value of another fixture

Tags: python, pytest

I have an object with a `side` parameter that determines the behavior of the object.  I've created a fixture for the valid values of `side`, and an associated fixture to produce an object initialized with the given value of `side`.

The part that's giving me trouble is that I want to test the behavior of my object on various integers and strings (simplification for example purposes), but the exact values I want to pass to my tests depend on the value of `side`.  I'm currently achieving this by creating a dictionary of lists, and returning the entire list depending on `side`, but this isn't ideal.

Example fixtures:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=['left', 'right'])
def side(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture
def my_obj(side):
    # some object that takes `side` as an arg
    return MyObj(side=side)

@pytest.fixture
def my_ints(side):
    # the ints I want to test depending on `side`
    mapping = {'left': [0, 1, 2], 'right': [11, 22]}
    return mapping[side]

@pytest.fixture
def my_strs(side):
    # the strs I want to test depending on `side`
    mapping = {'left': list('ab'), 'right': list('xyz')}
    return mapping[side]
```

The issue here is that `my_ints` and `my_strs` return a list but I want to test on the individual values within the lists, not the lists as a whole.  As a result, I'm forced to use a `for` loop within the tests.

Example tests:

```
def test_on_ints(my_obj, my_ints):
    for my_int in my_ints:
        # do the same general thing for each my_int
        assert my_obj.some_meth1(my_int) >= 0

def test_on_strs(my_obj, my_strs):
    for my_str in my_strs:
        # do the same general thing for each my_str
        assert 'foo' in my_obj.some_meth2(my_str)
```

This of course only runs each test once per value of `side`, giving me output along the lines of:

```
test_so_example.py::test_on_ints[left] PASSED
test_so_example.py::test_on_ints[right] PASSED
test_so_example.py::test_on_strs[left] PASSED
test_so_example.py::test_on_strs[right] PASSED
```

Ideally, I'd like to remove the `for` loop from my tests, and have the tests run for each value in the list.  Basically producing test output like:

```
test_so_example.py::test_on_ints[left-0] PASSED
test_so_example.py::test_on_ints[left-1] PASSED
test_so_example.py::test_on_ints[left-2] PASSED
test_so_example.py::test_on_ints[right-11] PASSED
test_so_example.py::test_on_ints[right-22] PASSED
(likewise for test_on_strs)
```

Is what I want to do possible?  Is there a different structure that would make this easier?

In practice I'll be doing this over many tests, with more than two values for sides, so I'd like to avoid having to explicitly write out all the `(side, int/str/etc)` pairs.

I've read over some answers involving indirect parametrization, but couldn't get anything to work, and not sure if that's the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

> I've read over some answers involving indirect parametrization, but
>   couldn't get anything to work, and not sure if that's the right
>   approach.

If what you want is to validate all the possible combinations from one or more sides, each with one or more values, and have those validations report PASS/FAIL in a separate test, on a separate line, for each, then pytest test generation should address your use case.

[This paragraph](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html#_pytest.python.Metafunc.parametrize) looks daunting, but look over it a couple times and practice with a very basic example, then attempt what you require, which might look something like this:

conftest.py

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if set(['value', 'expected']).issubset(set(metafunc.fixturenames)):
        metafunc.parametrize('side', ['left', 'right'])
        metafunc.parametrize('value, expected', [(1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)])
```

test_some_stuff.py

```
def test_can_use_parameterization(side, value, expected):
    assert value * 0 == expected

test_some_stuff.py::test_can_use_parameterization[left-1-0] ✓                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           17% █▋
 test_some_stuff.py::test_can_use_parameterization[left-2-0] ✓                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           33% ███▍
 test_some_stuff.py::test_can_use_parameterization[left-3-0] ✓                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           50% █████
 test_some_stuff.py::test_can_use_parameterization[right-1-0] ✓                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          67% ██████▋
 test_some_stuff.py::test_can_use_parameterization[right-2-0] ✓                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          83% ████████▍
 test_some_stuff.py::test_can_use_parameterization[right-3-0] ✓                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         100% ██████████

Results (0.04s):
       6 passed
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you want but it gives the test output you desire:

```
import pytest


class MyObj:
    """Dummy Obj so tests are runnable"""
    def __init__(self, side="left"):
        self.side = side

    def some_meth1(self, i):
        return i

    def some_meth2(self, i):
        return 'foo'


def get_int_data():
    """This could come from a file or anywhere else..."""
    return [('left', 0), ('left', 1), ('left', 2), ('right', 11), ('right', 12)]


@pytest.mark.parametrize('side, my_int', get_int_data())
def test_on_ints(side, my_int):
    assert MyObj(side=side).some_meth1(my_int) >= 0


@pytest.mark.parametrize('side, my_str', [
  ('left', 'ab'),
  ('right', 'xyz'),
])
def test_on_strs(side, my_str):
    assert 'foo' in MyObj(side=side).some_meth2(my_str)
```

Results:

```
test_so_example.py::test_on_ints[left-0] PASSED                                                                                                                                        [ 14%]
test_so_example.py::test_on_ints[left-1] PASSED                                                                                                                                        [ 28%]
test_so_example.py::test_on_ints[left-2] PASSED                                                                                                                                        [ 42%]
test_so_example.py::test_on_ints[right-11] PASSED                                                                                                                                      [ 57%]
test_so_example.py::test_on_ints[right-12] PASSED                                                                                                                                      [ 71%]
test_so_example.py::test_on_strs[left-ab] PASSED                                                                                                                                       [ 85%]
test_so_example.py::test_on_strs[right-xyz] PASSED                                                                                                                                     [100%
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is specifically what I said I wanted to avoid doing in my question.

Comment: @root Gotcha, fair enough. FWIW, I've updated my answer (see `get_int_data` change). I can see why you wouldn't want to hardcode it into the decorator but surely the pairs are defined _somewhere_ and you can load them in and easily transform them into the tuple format this wants.